# Inserting data in Mongo DB using java and retrieve the data from Mongo DB using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, mongo-java

I am new to Mongo DB can we insert the data in java and retrieve the data from Mongo DB using java script?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look into mongodb [quick start](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart)
2. Take a look into mongodb java [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial). Here you can find how to connect/query/update mongodb.
3. To retrieve data from mongodb via javascript create some service layer (it can be simple rest api) that will return data in [json](http://www.json.org/) format for example.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript way of printing output of MongoDB query to a file

1] create a javascript file

test.js

```
cursor = db.printShardingStatus();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
  printjson(cursor.next());
}
```

2] run

```
mongo admin --quiet test.js > output.txt
```